# pandas isin with custom container (how to make it "list like")

Tags: python, pandas

[Pandas `isin` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) (from `Dataframe` and `Series`) requires a set or a "list like" container as an argument.

I need to test elements of a Series for appartenance to a set of words, a small minority of which are not entirely defined : a star replaces one or more letter at a given position in the word. An example set would be : `{ 'abcd', 'dbca', 'd1*' }`

I figured that list-like meant that the container implements the `__contains__` method, so I created a custom container containing a `set` for entirely defined words (that's to benefit from the speed of look-ups) and a list for the rest of the words with stars that are tested separately. That logic is handled by a custom `__contains__` method.

But my `custom_set` is rejected because it is not deemed "list-like".

Any idea what pandas would consider as list-like ?

Or of an alternative approach that also relies on built-in pandas functions (my understanding is that `Dataframe`'s methods are more performant than `apply`ing custom functions

Comment: can you provide an example dataframe?

Comment: Is list conversion an option?

Comment: @mozway Not really but a Series of random strings with between 3 and 9 alphanumeric characters would be equivalent for that purpose

Comment: Can you provide a **dummy** (yet meaningful) example? It's easier to help with a example ;)

Comment: @jlandercy what do you mean? To convert it into a list I shoud first replace star-containing words (like '*OLO') by all valid combinations

Comment: @mozway : ok I'll do it as soon as I can

Comment: Also add the error you have if any.

Comment: `list-like` doesn't have to means it has to have `__contains__` but it may need other functions (i.e. to iterate items). I found [pandas.api.types.is_list_like](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_list_like.html) and it suggests that `Series` is also `list-like`. Maybe you should create class based on `Series` and replace `__contains__`.

Comment: digging in source code I found [is_list_like](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L1121) and it check if class has `__iter__`